# User gets access denied to css files and js files even though user is logged in

Tags: css, user-access

We are using wordpress as a intranet, we have the AD Integration plugin. Everything is working fine except for one user. Now there is no difference in settings on his machine or user profile or AD profile to any other user. But for some reason when he logs in he gets access denied to all the CSS files and JS files.

I know he has logged in successfully because I use console.log to display the username when logged in as well as other details such as full name and job title. The details are retrieved from the wordpress function for current_user so I know he is logged in. Has anyone else had issues with style sheets etc being denied even though the user is logged in?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most typical WordPress configurations the load of CSS/JS assets is *not* actually processed by WordPress core. Otherwise the performance would be *horrible*.

Web servers do fantastic work at serving static files like that though, so WP's configuration (`.htaccess` or other, depending on server) just passes all such files to them.

It's not clear from your description:

- if that user can access files when *not* logged in
- if *specific* files cannot be accessed or definitely *all* files

WP admin uses PHP for concatenation of assets, which does tend to cause issues now then. You can try setting `SCRIPT_DEBUG` constant to `true` in configuration to disable it (as well as minified versions) and see if that makes a difference.

But for completely static assets this is unlikely to be caused by WordPress core in general. Check server logs for clues, especially if you are running security and/or firewall modules on it.

Comment: the page loads just with text no images styling nothing so it must be something inside the htaccess, were using kerberos protcol so will go through all the logs on the linux server. Thank you